# where is the specific button on design mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

how can i find the specific button on design mode where i have several buttons ie: hundered of buttons so that they all like spaghetti and one button may be under another button or a groupbox (i might be playing with the visibilities ) and i want to see my button number 83 on the design. how can i see him? where is he hiding? :) i use visual studio as an IDE. thanks.

```
MessageBox.Show(" where is the specific button? i know that he is somewhere on the form but cant distinguish it on the design since its somewhere under something i cant find it");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Document Outline (View - Other Windows - Document Outline)

Just pick the button from the tree and voila.

PS: this works for other types of designers (WPF/Silverlight, ASP.NET)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can access it via the Properties Window. There is a drop-down that will list all of the items in your form in design mode.

[image]

Then use the drop-down.  The drop-down will list all of the items on your form so you will scroll through the list to find Button number 83.

[image]

Images were pulled from [MS Visual Studio: The properties Window](http://www.functionx.com/vcsharp/windows/propwnd.htm) which contains an explanation of the window.

Comment: thank you i voted your answer and it helps some but iamruss anwswer fits more in my case because with his solution i can see if my button is inside a groupbox or so.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the properties window?

[image]

Comment: i click on a button on design mode and check if its the specific button but not. and randomly do this but cant find. so if u mean this sure i tried using the properties window but since there are lots of buttons its hard to do and a button can be under a groupbox so how can i find him?

Comment: The dropdown comboboxy on the top allows you to select the desired button by name.

Comment: thank you Matzi bluefeet showed it more clearly but in my case iamruss solution helped alot becaouse we can see it a button is inside a groupbox or so( can derive more information with iamruss way )hence i chose his answer but i voted you up also.